# HTML/CSS button - scroll down to another section

Tags: html, css

I'm thinking about one process with my website.
I created a button via CSS/HTML and I would like to click on in and croll down to another section in website (scroll down to website)

It is possible to process without javascript ?

Answer (score 4):

Use  `scroll-behavior: smooth;` on html elemnt:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.empty{
     height:1000px;
     background: repeating-linear-gradient(
      45deg,
      #606dbc,
      #606dbc 10px,
      #465298 10px,
      #465298 20px
    );
}
```

```html
<a id="#top" href="#bottom">Click for smooth scroll to bottom</a>
<div class="empty"></div>
<a href="#top" id="bottom">Back to top</a>
<div class="empty"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this in ur css file..

```css
body{
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Comment: this will not scroll-down to another section. It is a property to scroll instead of jumping if you use it in combination witn anchor targeting an id

Comment: Oh Man for that you have to right down the HTML Code as well, for example.. 
 in HTML FILE:
<button href="#section1"></button>
<div id="section1">This is Section 1</div>

In CSS File:
body{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}